# permission errors with python/django

Tags: permissions, python, django

Error can be seen here: http://djaffry.selfip.com:8080/

If i go to the folder /srv/twingle/search and do `ls -l` I get

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    65142784 May 26 20:28 words.db
```

I gave it 777 access (absolutely unsafe, I know, but I thought it would atleast work)

any idea what can be the permissions problem?

Edit: A very strange problem is that the code doesn't crash once every few refreshes.. then goes back to crashing

Comment: Are you using SELinux?

Comment: Cristian: How can I check if I'm using it, what are the repercussions of using it?

Comment: What distribution are you using? SELinux adds another layer of security above the traditional layer used by all Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: Run `/usr/sbin/getenforce` and check if it's set to *Enforcing*.

Comment: yes it's enforcing,

`[tipu@localhost ~]$ /usr/sbin/getenforce
Enforcing
`

Comment: I am using CentOS 5.4

Comment: In this case could you run `setenforce 0` and see if the error is still present? This will set SELinux to the permissive mode, which means that denials will only be logged. You can return the the initial setup by running `setenforce 1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the webserver/mod_python user have `r-x` on the directory `/srv/twingle/search' e.g. all the way down (look with ls -ld /srv /srv/twingle /srv/twingle/search)
2. I make it that it works/delivers a page 1 out of 5 times (does that tally in with something, numer of processes or such like?).
3. Django Version: 1.2.1 pre-alpha is on there. 1.2.1 is released. Is it possible to upgrade to the release version?

Comment: Davey, after running your command:

drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 May 23 23:27 /srv

drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 May 25 14:32 /srv/twingle

drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 May 27 04:12 /srv/twingle/search
`

I will update Django. Yes, it works/delivers only 1 out of 5 times and I don't know why

Comment: What happens if you run it up in the built in webserver in django?

Comment: davey, that's a good thing to check.. let me see.

Comment: If it were permissions or Christian's suggestion of selinux then it ought to be broken completely/all the time rather than intermittently working. When you run it under the built in you may be using a different userid to when it runs as apache and that may give a clue a to what's wrong.